# How to make validation in setState?

Tags: javascript

I have a datalist , on change I have a  function , that checks value was picked from options or typed new value. Depending on that I'm assigning it to variable "address_id" or "new_address" . In the end I need to make object and store it in state. The problem is I need to put only one value that is not null.

If address_id is null, so in object should be new_address. And if new_address is null, in object address_id.

```
address_id=null

tempObj: {
  new_address: new_address,
},
```

How to make validation which checks what variable is not null and put it in object.

```
  onChooseAddress(e, idx) {
    const { adresses } = this.state
    let address_id = null
    let new_address = null

    for (let i = 0; i < adresses.length; i++) {
      if (
        e.target.value === adresses[i].address &&
        e.target.name === "address"
      ) {
        address_id = adresses[i].id
      }
    }

    if (!address_id && e.target.name === "address") {
      new_address = e.target.value
    }


    // Here I need make validation!!!
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      tempObj: {
        ...prevState.tempObj,
       // address_id: address_id or new_address: new_address,
      },
    }))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a normal function that returns the state object.

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  // do validations here

  return {
    tempObj: {
      ...prevState.tempObj,
     // address_id: address_id or new_address: new_address,
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 let existingaddr = addresses.find( (address) => e.target.value === 
 address.address && e.target.name === 'address' )

 let tmpObj = { 
   ...prevState.tempObj 
 }    

 if( existingaddr ){
     tmpObj.address_id = existingaddr.id;
 }
 else{
   tmpObj.new_address = e.target.value
 }

 this.setState(prevState => (tmpObj))
```

I didnt test it, but the idea is to create an object, which will have one key or the other, and then spread in into your temp object. Hopefully I understand what you were trying to accomplish.

EDIT:
I changed it up a bit and put it in a [code pen](https://codepen.io/SpringsTea/pen/vMwJrV). It follows your usecase as far as I can tell.

Comment: I got you idea, but it overrides  address_id property all the time with new_address, even if there suppossed to be  address_id

Comment: Could pls send me again your link in codepen, I can't open it

Comment: @YerlanYeszhanov Sorry, I messed the link up, fixed.